# Вызов List из метода выдает kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Добрый день, у меня не получается получить данные из List в методе getUser(), так как выскакивает ошибка о том что List не имеет данные. Хотя они там есть, в методе ParserKtJson() в логе отображаться данные.

```
        class ParserKtJson {

        private var users: List<User>? = null

        fun createFromJson(mJson: String): ParserKtJson {
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val pj = ParserKtJson()
            pj.users = Arrays.asList(*gson.fromJson(mJson, Array<User>::class.java))
            Log.d("**** **** ***", pj.users!!.get(1).id.toString()) // 2
            getUser()
            return pj


        }

        fun getUser(): List<User>? {
            val pj = ParserKtJson()
            Log.d("**** ****", pj.users!!.get(1).id.toString()) // kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
            return users;
        }
    }
```

Лог

```
Process: ua.com.developmentunderandroid.developmentunderandroid, PID: 8886
                                                                                                      kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                                                                                                          at ua.com.developmentunderandroid.developmentunderandroid.web.kt.ParserKtJson.getUser(ParserKtJson.kt:28)
                                                                                                          at ua.com.developmentunderandroid.developmentunderandroid.web.kt.ParserKtJson.ParserKtJson(ParserKtJson.kt:21)
                                                                                                          at ua.com.developmentunderandroid.developmentunderandroid.KtWeb.parsingKt(KtWeb.kt:97)
                                                                                                          at ua.com.developmentunderandroid.developmentunderandroid.KtWeb$ProgressTask.onPostExecute(KtWeb.kt:57)
                                                                                                          at ua.com.developmentunderandroid.developmentunderandroid.KtWeb$ProgressTask.onPostExecute(KtWeb.kt:41)
                                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
                                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут

```
fun getUser(): List<User>? {
    val pj = ParserKtJson()
    Log.d("**** ****", pj.users!!.get(1).id.toString()) // kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    return users;
}
```

вы в переменную pj кладёте экземпляр класса ParserKtJson. В нём поле `users` явно инициализированно как `null`. После вы к нему обращаетесь и ожидаемо падаете.

Видимо вы имели в виду, что у вас вызовется коструктор, на коий похож метод `fun ParserKtJson` - но это не конструктор и вы этот метод нигде не вызываете.

Comment: Извините, я допустил ошибку в имени метода. На самом деле конструктор я не описывал. Я пробовал и без экземпляра `Log.d("**** ****", users!!.get(1).id.toString())` не помогло. На Java тоже была такая проблема, я её решил указав List<User> static

Comment: У меня получилось взять данные из List таким образом `var kt = ParserKtJson();
           contentView!!.text = kt.createFromJson(content).getUser()!!.get(0).id.toString()
`

Comment: Получается, что так быстро данные уничтожаются из List?

Comment: @Sergiyss Вы в каждом методе создаете новый объект класса `ParserKtJson` следовательно `users` всегда будет null, нужно возвращать `this`